# Using Youtube as video storage for my app

Tags: flutter, youtube

I am still relatively new to these topics.
I am programming my app in Flutter and I can already use Flutter to play a foreign video from Youtube in the app.

I want to upload in Youtube all my video resources as private to be able to display them in my app.

Is there any documentation on how to do this? What are the costs per request?

Is Youtube even right for such a mobile app?`
I was going to use Firebase cloud storage, but think that can get very expensive once I release the app.

What other options would I have?

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't really suitable for StackOverflow, since it's basically just asking whether you can use YouTube.

That being said, as long as you don't violate the T&C of YouTube and you're fine with storing all your videos on their platform, yes, you can do this. Using YouTube this way is free as of now. But note that there is a difference between "private" and "unlisted".

Comment: What do you mean with private and unlisted?
And how can it be free? Imagine my app has a few million users. If all of them watch videos that are around 5-10 Mb and 5 seconds long.
Then a lot of requests take place. That must cost a lot. Is there documentation about how much i have to pay for a request?

Comment: I would like to encourage you to search for questions yourself first. That being said, YouTube has [different privacy settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177) for videos. Using YouTube as a pure hosting platform is likely a violation of their T&C. You can't pay YouTube, they're not a video hosting platform (like Vimeo or Wistia).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a profile on youtube, upload as many videos as you want and list them as unlisted, meaning you can only find the video if you have the link, then in your app link the vides to whatever selection method you have. so ex I have a button when clicked launches a specific unlisted youtube url link and plays the video.

It would be the same as if someone was searching your  video publicly and playing it, both are free.